# Calculating output from kernel

Tags: machine-learning, kernel-trick, computer-vision

Given the following task:

You feed an image $I$ with the dimensions $200\text{x}200\text{x}3$ in the convolutional layer, which consists of $12323$ kernels $K$ each with the size $40\text{x}40\text{x}3$. What dimensions of the output $O$ do you expect?

The formula for calculating the kernel is in my understanding the following:

$O = [I-K]+1$

With:

$O=\text{output}$

$I=\text{input}$

$K=\text{kernel}$

The solution offered from the professor is $O=81,81,12313$ but if I use the formula then I get

$O=200-40+1$

which is $161,161$ for applying the kernel on one image. But because we have $12323$ kernels the result is $161,161,12323$.

Why does my result differ from that one of my professor?

### Update 1

I found out that for getting to the result the kernel $K$ was multiplied by $3$. I still ask myself why I do not also multiply the size of the input $I$ by $3$? Still why does my professor uses $12313$ and not $12323$?

### Update 2

The kernel $K$ was not multilplied by three. I have overlooked that an stride $S=2$ was given which results in the new formula

$O = \frac{[I-K]+1}{2}$

Still why does my professor uses $12313$ and not $12323$?

Comment: What about 34 in kernel dimensions? Do you have a source?

Comment: Typo. Dimension is 3. @gunes

Comment: Stride=2 makes sense and I think your professor just made a typo about 12313.

Comment: I think also that he made a typo. @gunes